# Does tracking users violate open source license?

Tags: etiquette

I'm making an open-source software product (that runs natively on a user's machine) and I'm interested in how often the software is being used. What I'd like is: If the software is used for more than X minutes (with X being really high), ping a server somewhere to increase an anonymous tally.

I know that stuff like this is done all of the time with proprietary products (not to mention web apps), but does doing something like this in an open-source context violate unwritten norms?

Comment: Why do you think it would violate FLOSS licenses?

Comment: If this worries you, make it very public somewhere in the project files/on the website, and provide an alternative makefile, which builds without that functionality enabled (or other easy way to disable it; for instance, dropping an empty file called dont_track_me into the app's directory, or some such)

Answer (score 7):

It doesn't violate normal free software licences, and it's not unheard of.  The email client [alpine](https://www.washington.edu/alpine/), released under Apache v2, on first invocation (and, if memory serves, after major upgrades) displays this message:

> SPECIAL REQUEST: This software was originally created and maintained
>   as a public service by the University of Washington until 2009;
>   updates are made available as a public service of the Alpine
>   community. It is always helpful to have an idea of how many users are
>   using Alpine. Are you willing to be counted as an Alpine user?
>   Pressing Return will send an anonymous (meaning, your real email
>   address will not be revealed) message to the Alpine developers for
>   purposes of tallying.

Note, however, that they are very up-front about what they're doing, and the notification is opt-in - that is, the user must take an affirmative action to permit it.  If you're not very clear about what you're doing and why, or you don't provide an easy opt-out, you may well find that your software gets recompiled without the tracking option in it - which free software is specifically designed to permit - and that the non-treacherous version quickly becomes more popular.